# Lift Rest's auto conversion is not working

Tags: scala, rest, scala-2.8, lift

I have below Rest class

```
object MyRest extends RestHelper {
  override implicit val formats =
    net.liftweb.json.DefaultFormats + BigDecimalSerializer

  serveJx[MyRest.AutoJsonXmlAble] {
    case "api" :: "static" :: "item" :: itemId :: Nil Get _ =>
      auto(
        new Item(
          itemId,
          "Name",
          "Disc",
          BigDecimal(5),
          true,
          12,
          12
        )
      )
  }
}
```

And Model class as below

```
case class Item(id: String, name: String,
                description: String,
                price: BigDecimal, taxable: Boolean,
                weightInGrams: Int, qnty: Int)
```

But when I run the app I get below output

```
curl -H"Accept:application/json" http://localhost:8080/api/static/item/1234
{
  "id":"1234",
  "name":"Name",
  "description":"Disc",
  "price":5.0,
  "taxable":true,
  "weightInGrams":12,
  "qnty":12
}

curl -H"Accept:application/xml" http://localhost:8080/api/static/item/1234
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<id>1234</id>
```

What is wrong here? I am trying to use auto conversion between XML and JSON. And where can I detailed information about rest module in lift?

**Update:**
I think problem is with root tag. As seen from above XML output there is no root tag. Can any one guide me how can I have root tag using serveJx?